# VSTO: How to implement Office Standard Custom Task Pane TabContainer

Tags: controls, vsto, customtaskpane

I'm looking for a simple way to implement the standard office custom Task pane TabContainer which looks like this one:
[Standard Office TabContainer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sm5M2.jpg)

(1) is easy to implement
(2) with the TabContainer there is a way to use Icons also - but they don't look so nice like in this one with mouse over effect etc.
(3) I didn't found in the standard TabContainer a setting to enable such a line with a marker

Is this a separate component or does anybody has an example what all is needed to have such a control?

Answer (score 0):

Office has a history of using controls that it doesn't expose to third party devs. The recent files lists for example, are not re-usable, among others.

But maybe they didn't do that this time, maybe they did make it available. They'd probably include it in some release notes, right? But it's not listed in `What's new for developers` for either [Word 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838936.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) or [Office 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj229830.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in general.

Okay, maybe they just forgot to include it there? I also took a look through intellisense where I might expect to find it but did not. A bit of googling isn't coming up with anything either.

I don't think this is something you can re-use.

You can of course re-create it. It might be easiest with WPF, but only relatively speaking, It's probably not going to be easy, overall. Also, if you go this route, you need separate and more specific questions than "How do I do this?" Go try to do it, and ask questions related to the roadblocks you run into.